# Run scons from directory upstream in the hierarchy

Tags: directory, scons

I would like to run scons from a directory different from the one which contains the `SConstruct file`. This directory is upstream in the hierarchy.

I know the command `scons -u` will search upwards in the directory tree for an `SConstruct file`. Does an option exist which will search downwards ?

Thanks

Comment: you can use -C to point to working directory

Comment: Hcorg - you should put that as an answer. It is correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

as @hcorg above stated:

```
scons -C <path to  your subdir>
```